# CodeIgniter ORM on existing application

Tags: php, codeigniter, orm, doctrine, codeigniter-datamapper

I have an existing application built on CodeIgniter which leverages the default CI ActiveRecord approach for handling database records from the models. I'd like to make this more object driven by implementing a simple ORM for handling CRUD processes and relationships.

Is it possible to do this on top of my existing application structure, i.e. for example implement an 'Objects' directory that the models call for CRUD processes? Is it best to create something or use Doctrine,DataMapper,Gas which are all solutions I've looked at but the docs recommend they replace the CI Models.

I'd like to avoid re-engineering the existing structure and logic within the Models, but would like to implement more of an object driven approach.

Thanks!

Comment: I have worked on a number of projects which use a combination of DataMapper and standard CI models. I have not run into any issues using both. Datamapper is super easy to install and get running in an established project.

Comment: Hi, many thanks - please forgive my ignorance but how would you install datampper in parallel to the CI 'models' is it possible to simply create an 'objects' folder for the datamapper classes, and how would they be invoked from the CI models? (any conflicts on names?)

Comment: You install it per the instructions. Then any models you want to use CI would `extend CI_Model` and would be loaded in the controllers with `$this->load->model()`. And models you want to use DataMapper would `extend DataMapper` and be loaded in the controller using `new Class()`

Answer (score 0):

I've been in that situation and my solution was creating a standalone library with CI-agnostic code (integrating Composer for autoloading and Doctrine for database connections). All these classes could then be called and instantiated from within the standard CI flow, but also easily moved into a new (non CI) project.

Comment: Thanks Freddie, would it be possible to use DocTrine in another folder and call from CI models allowing me to gradually replace Activerecord implementations?